# JavaScript Object attributes randomly turn to NaN after few correct iterations in a loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a simple canvas game with moving shapes. When I update the position of the ship in a loop it works only for a couple of frames then the object becomes undefined and the x,y attributes of the object become NaN and the velocity becomes something like 1.137658463e-16

I'm almost positive it is a problem with the update function but I'm not sure what is wrong here. I had the console print the object in the iteration and here are some snippets before and after

```
//before
x: 300,
  y: 296,
  angle: 0,
  velocity: 0.40000000000000013,
  update: [Function],
  isThrusting: false,
  maxVelocity: 8,
//after
x: NaN,
  y: NaN,
  angle: NaN,
  velocity: -0.3999999999999999,
  update: [Function],
  isThrusting: false,
  maxVelocity: 8,
```

```
//Code 

var gameState = {
  ships: {}
}

var Entity   = function(x,y,angle){
    var self = {
        x:x,
        y:y,
        angle:angle,
        velocity:2
    }
    self.update = function(){
      self.x += self.velocity * Math.sin(self.angle);
      self.y -= self.velocity * Math.cos(self.angle);
    }
    return self;
}

var Ship = function(x,y,angle){
  var self = Entity(x,y,angle);
  self.isThrusting =  false;
  self.maxVelocity =  8;
  self.bullets = {};
  self.update = function(){
    if(self.isThrusting){
      self.velocity += 1;
      self.x += self.velocity * Math.sin(self.angle);
      self.y -= self.velocity * Math.cos(self.angle);
      if(self.velocity >= self.maxVelocity){
          self.velocity = self.maxVelocity;
        }

      }else {
        if(self.velocity > 0){
            self.velocity -= 0.4;
            self.x += self.velocity * Math.sin(self.angle);
            self.y -= self.velocity * Math.cos(self.angle);
          }
  }

  }

  return self;
}

//here I initialize the object
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  gameState.ships[socket.id] = new Ship(300,300, 0);
});

//here is the loop of the update
setInterval(function(){

  for(var i in gameState.ships);
    var ship = gameState.ships[i];
    ship.update();
}

}, 1000/60);
```

Comment: Notice how the angle is also NaN. Since you don’t set it in `update`, the problem is elsewhere, e.g. in how ships are created. Don’t iterate over arrays using `for in`, by the way – use `forEach`.

Comment: @Ry- Yeah Ry I noticed that the entire object becomes undefined after a few iteration, almost half a second. What puzzles me is that it works perfectly fine on the first 30ish iterations. I edited the code to show how I'm creating the object. And regarding the for in ships here is a map between every object and their id, why is for in bad here? I'm somewhat new to JavaScript

Comment: I'm on a phone and might have missed it, but where are you updating your object's `angle`? If you aren't then I guess your ships only move on the y axis because sin(0) is 0 IIRC, and anything * 0 will be 0. Sure that doesn't give the NaN yet, but it may be from this missing bit. (We need an [mcve])

Comment: @Noor: Sorry, I didn’t realize `i` wasn’t a loop counter. Ignore that! But is there anywhere else you change angle or create new ships? Or does `gameState`/`gameState.ships` get serialized/deserialized/replaced?

Comment: @Ry- The issue was sort of the angle. I'm using the mouse coordinates to calculate it but sometimes these coordinates are null when the cursor is off the canvas. I managed to fix it by setting a default value for the cursor X/Y positions. Thanks for the hint and the note on using for in!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm calculating the angle of the ship depending on the position of the cursor on the canvas. This issue is happening when I start the game and my mouse is outside the canvas only which sends an empty variable causing this problem...I fixed it by setting a default value for the cursor position until the cursor was touching the canvas.